# When android facebook Development Key Hashes has validity

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I'm having trouble with facebook development key hash.

I try to share content into facebook using [Feed Dialog as fallback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkfeed)
as showing in Facebook quick start page. I've already done whole step set for adding facebook SDK in my Android project.
I've set a development key hash of application and add it into "Add your development and release key hashes" field, after I generated debug apk file of application.
Trying sharing with my device where Facebook app is running with my developer account logged (the same on which i've registered the application) all works fine.
When i trying to sharing content with another device where is running Facebook app, but with different Facebook account error

> com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: This app has no Android
>   key hashes configured.  Configure your app key hashes at -my application settings page-

My question is development key hash is limited only for developer testing so it works only with developer account interactions?

Ps: I made application public and available to all users on settings account, I set a development key hash given by application installed on test devices, but i didn't set any release key hash.

Answer (score 0):

**Login to facebook dev account and go to status and reviews under app sections and tick (Do you want to make this app and its all features available to general public to yes )**

Comment: Already done..I've also written in the text of the question -_-

Comment: generally changes on facebook takes time

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the hash keys on the facebook developer site which will be acheived from ur code programmatically.

it with sync with package name.

Comment: Done...maybe I forgot to write it in text of question.

Answer (score 0):

You can dive into your app management,and getting started,as such:
https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/664900340309697/?platform=android
then it has some steps,you should step by step and config your app's package name and lancher activity just finished.